# Step over EventEmitter to the listeners in debugger

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, electron

Node has a class, `EventEmitter`, that is a pretty common fixture of node.js and electron programming. Unfortunately it's a PITA to debug. Imagine some code like this

```
import EventEmitter from `events`;

const emitter = new EventEmitter();

emitter.on('foobar', handleFoobar);

emitter.emit('foobar', 'foo', 'bar');

function handleFoobar(..args) {
  console.log(...args);
}
```

Now I want to step through the code in the debugger. Of course in this small example I can put a breakpoint on `handleFoobar` but, in *real code* I just want to be able to step through the code, when I get to `someEmitter.emit` I want to be able to pick something along the lines of *"Step Into Listeners"*.

Unfortunately no such feature exists AFAIK. [The implementation of `EventEmitter` is fairly complex](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js) so stepping in to see get to the listeners requires stepping about 20-25 times. You can set breakpoints at all the exit points but there are at least 6 of them which is also annoying when you want to turn them all on/off.

[image]

Are there any other creative solutions to effectively implement something like "Step Into Listeners" when on a `someEmitter.emit` line?

One solution comes to mind which is to replace `events.js` with a simpler implementation. Without domain support and using ES6 features it could be much smaller implementation like

```
EventEmitter.prototype.emit(type, ...args) {
  const listeners = this._listeners[type].slice();
  listeners.forEach(listener => {
    listener(...args);
  }
  return listeners > 0;
}
```

I suppose I could also patch that into the prototype if `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'`

Are there any other more generic solutions? Like maybe a debugger feature where I can pick code to never step into directly but picking step into in the debugger comes out of its exit points?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. It's called *blackblocking*

You can set by script filenames which files not to step into so, adding `events.js` to the list does exactly what I want. When I'm on the `someEmitter.emit` and I press "Step Into" I come out the listeners immediately!

[image]